# Drupal 7 Not Recognizing Correct .htaccess in Files directory. Why?

Tags: .htaccess, security, drupal-7

I have the following in my Drupal 7.38 installation's files directory --

```
#SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

Additionally, since this this directory has been set to be the private files path and drupal has been set to serve files in the files/tmp directory, it includes the follwoing command:

```
Deny from all
```

Now this is how it should be set up according to https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2013-003 but the Security Review Module is reporting the following ...

```
Security Review was able to execute a PHP file written to your files directory.

The .htaccess file is missing from the files directory at
```

Notice that the report does not complete by stating what the location is. My privately set files directory is sites/all/default/files. I don't know if I need a separate private files directory set up from this one. Setting this one for private is causing an issue with Ctools as well. I may just have to move back to a public file system, but I am combatting a security issue right now where spam bots are being placed on my web server and I am trying everything to get it locked down.

Any ideas on why I am getting this result from Security Review?

Comment: It could be your webserver is set up to ignore yout .htaccess files.

Comment: :O I will check in with the host. I would never have thought of that.

Comment: Consider this question closed. I reverted to a different files system and the message has changed.